# Чтение файла xml на сервере

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Есть сервер на шаблоне web API (asp) (файл конфигурации json). 
Мне необходимо загрузить файл в формате xml на сервер и прочитать данные из него. Гуглится сохранение файла или чтение массива байтов, а как прочитать данные из файла не записывая его куда-либо? 
Если можно, помогите примером реализации метода загрузки

Comment: `Request.Files[0].InputStream.Read` читайте данные. Можно обвернуть в ридер `XmlReader.Create(Request.Files[0].InputStream)` можно подрубить десериализацию... и т п.

Comment: Как я понял, нужно post-запросом отправить xml вашему серверу?

Comment: И уточните, у вас Core или нет? Если да, посмотрите мой ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594973/5045688).

Comment: Да, мне надо написать метод, в который с html форм приходит файл xml. Приложение .NET Core

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то читаем строкой XML файл в переменную а затем парсим.

```
public void parseXmlFromUrl(string url)
{
    String data = null;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        data = client.DownloadString(url);
    }

    if (data != null)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(data);

        // do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, у ТС свой сервер, на который этот самый файл и загружается

Comment: Мне надо на сервер получать файл, а не читать с сервера